# How to write python script to pass list of item in command prompt?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example:
I am passing list of item as argument in  command prompt following format :

```
  $test run -list1 ["one day", "one hour"] -list2 ["1234"]
```

after successful pass list1 and list2 output should be:

```
 list1: 
      type: list
      output format: ["one day", "one hour"]
 list2:
      type: list
      output formate: ["1234"]
```

Comment: why don't you just pass a string and use `string.split(',')` to get the list?

Comment: Will the command line _always_ be like that, with 2 lists named -list1 and -list2, or can the number of lists and their names vary?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module. The syntax will be a little bit different, though.

In your script, you can use the `argparse` module the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My awesome script doing stuff')
    parser.add_argument('--list1', metavar='V1', default=[], nargs='+', help='a string for the first list')
    parser.add_argument('--list2', metavar='V2', default=[], nargs='+', help='a string for the second list')

    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    print(arguments.list1)
    print(arguments.list2)
```

You can then call your script:

```
$./run.py --list1 "one day" "one hour" --list2 "1234"
```

You can use `nargs='*'` instead of `nargs='+'` to allow for empty lists such as `$./run.py --list1 --list2 "something" "something else"` instead of forcing omitting the argument name (as in `$./run.py --list2 "1234"`)

Comment: Is it possible to pass argument as following format: 
 $./run.py --list1 ["one day" "one hour"] --list2 [1234, 5678, 9087]

Comment: You won't be able to do so as easily. To start with, this argument sequence will be seen as `['run.py', '--list1', '[one day', 'one hour]', '--list2', '[1234,', '5678,', '9087]']` in `sys.argv`. You’ll have to add at least quotes or double quotes around the brackets in the command line. Then you’ll be able to retrieve the strings representing the list that you’ll have to convert using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)